# What happened to my graphics card?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, amd-radeon

What happened to my graphics card?

[image: Screenshot]

It happens after a while, and more in QT applications than in GTK. Lines don't disappear after moving the window or hiding it (forcing it to redraw).

My graphics card is Radeon 9200SE. I have two monitors attached to it. I use the `radeon` driver on Arch Linux.

Comment: Looks like overheating to me!  Could be a linux-specific issue I dont know of, though.

Comment: Peanut-Butter? +1 I agree it "looks" hot. But i doubt that is the real issue. unless this happens over time and a cold rig does not have this issue.  -Does it artifact During the Post/BIOS?Bootstrap?GUI ?bootup/Spash? after launching an App or Just when its been running all day?

Comment: I have a dual monitor configuration with the exact (looks  the same) phenomenon, but completely different hardware. Sony laptop with Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller. Starting to think this is a higher layer software issue. Doesn't happen in Windows (dual boot). Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a live boot CD and see if it happens with that too.  I would guess it does, pointing at a hardware problem.

Your symptons look exactly like what I have experienced.  I think that some of the tiny solder connections on your GPU have broken, which is a pretty common problem on laptop, X-Boxes and desktop PCs with poor case ventilation, as heat/cool action breaks the brittle solder.

What need to done (if this is the case) is a professional **BGA reflow**, which may not be worth it for an old graphics card.  You can attempt it yourself, using a IR thermometer and heatgun (I've done this on a couple of ThinkPad laptops, once worked), and some people have even claimed done it by sticking it in the oven, or even by using a blowtorch (check YouTube).

Comment: I have the exact same phenomenon (dual monitors) and this doesn't happen on Windows (dual boot). It doesn't smell like a hw problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's possibly an X-Window issue(or whatever desktop window rendering tool your using) since it shows up as a screenshot. Try a live CD and see if the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a video RAM problem on the card.  It's either overheating or defective.  Clean out the case and make sure it's well ventilated.  If not, try swapping the card.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely overheating. I'd suggest checking the airflow of your system.

Have you tried reinstalling the drivers?